# Using Split method

Tags: python

I know that `split()` separates words when ever there is a space, but is there a way to make it so it does it when for example `a` occurs

```
>>>word = 'hi mya name  is'
['hi my',' name is']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `split` takes an optional argument where you can specific a string to split on.

```
>>> word = 'hi mya name  is'
>>> words = word.split('a')
>>> words
['hi my', ' n', 'me  is']
```

You can also limit the number of splits with a second argument, to get your example output:

```
>>> word = 'hi mya name  is'
>>> words = word.split('a', 1)
>>> words
['hi my', ' name  is']
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting by 'a's:

```py
>>> 'hi mya name  is'.split('a')
['hi my', ' n', 'me  is']
```

If you want to split at the first occurrence of an a:

```py
>>> 'hi mya name  is'.split('a', 1)
['hi my',' name is']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` with *regex* `a(?=\s)`, this will split on `a` if it is followed by a white space:

```
import re
re.split(r"a(?=\s)", word)

# ['hi my', ' name  is']
```